# Adding header file to Podspec

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm trying to work out how to add a header file to a specific Podspec. I currently have to manually drag the file into the Pod's group in Xcode to get it to build. Otherwise it complains it cannot find the header file. I'd like to take this step out of the build process. I'm still learning the ins and outs of declaring dependencies in Cocoapods.

The Podspec is as follows:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'ReactNativeCouchbaseLite'
  s.version          = '0.3.0'
  s.summary          = 'couchbase lite binding for react-native'
  s.license          = 'MIT'
  s.platform     = :ios, '7.0'
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.authors      = 'Fraser Xu <xvfeng123@gmail.com>'
  s.homepage     = 'https://github.com/fraserxu/react-native-couchbase-lite.git'
  s.source       = { :git => 'https://github.com/fraserxu/react-native-couchbase-lite.git' }
  s.source_files = 'ios/**/*.{h,m}'
  s.dependency 'couchbase-lite-ios'
  s.dependency 'couchbase-lite-ios/Listener'

  # Current attempt to add the header file
  s.subspec 'CBLRegisterJSViewCompiler' do |ss|
    ss.source_files = 'Extras/CBLRegisterJSViewCompiler.h'
    ss.preserve_paths = 'CouchbaseLite.framework'
    ss.vendored_frameworks = 'CouchbaseLite.framework'
    ss.dependency 'couchbase-lite-ios'
  end
end
```

The header I need to add is `CBLRegisterJSViewCompiler.h`. In the release download of couchbase-lite-ios this header appears in the `Extras` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your subspec.

```
ss.public_header_files = 'Extras/CBLRegisterJSViewCompiler.h'
```

[Link back to CocoaPods reference](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#public_header_files).

Comment: This didn't work - I'm waiting on a proposed change to the couchbase-lite-ios package that would include that part of the library by default.